# Having issues adding a photo to XML file

Tags: html, xml, image, photo

Hello and thanks for looking into my issue, I am currently working with an XML file that is being pulled to create a directory list. What I am trying to achieve here is to display an image next to the person's name but it seems like no matter how I link it the image it doesn't display on the browser.

I have tried to add the image as ,

```
<profile>
<lastname>Sample Last name</lastname>
<firstname>Sample First name</firstname>
<middlename></middlename>
<lastfirstname>First_Last</lastfirstname>
<indextitle><![CDATA[Dean]]></indextitle>
<photo>photo.jpg</photo>

<bio>
<![CDATA[<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>]]>
</bio>
</profile>
```

Comment: How are you converting that XML into something displayable? (Or are you just relying on a browser's ability to display XML?)

Comment: I have a PHP file that has an include for a .inc file and the inc file is pulling the XML to display it on the web. @Richard

Comment: Well your processing needs to convert the XML to something the browser will understand (ie. HTML). For specifics you need to show exactly what you are doing in the question.